# Google cast SDK incompatible for api>24?

Tags: java, android, casting, sdk, chromecast

I received feedbacks from users that the cast button wouldn't show up.

At first I thought the problem might be  that my app was not properly published since I was the only one being able to see the button.

After a few tests, the cast receiver app and the cast device do not seem to be the problem.I figured it might be a compatibility issue since the button wouldn't show up for devices running api>= 26 but would on api 24.

Upgrading my implementations and my api from 24 to 27 target doesn't solve the problem.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'AppId'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName '1.1'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'
    implementation 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.2.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.sofakingforever.libraries:iconpack:0.0.7@aar'
}
```

Note: firebase isn't at its highest version because gms and firebase have to be a the same version.

I have exactly the same issue using the sample app "cast hello world" from the [Cast documentations](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads). It works on api 24 but not higher.

Here is my Options.java:

```
public class Options implements OptionsProvider {

  @Override

  public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
    return new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.cast_app_id))
            .build();
}

@Override
public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is my menu inflater:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
// Setup the menu item for connecting to cast devices
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
return true;
}
```

Please help.